# How can I inspect a docker container's filesystem that cannot run?

Tags: docker, container

I recently was trying to inspect how this container works, and so I wanted to do what I'd typically do for a running container, mainly:

```
$ docker exec -it <container SHA> /bin/bash
```

However in this scenario I'm not able, nor do I want to, fully set up and run this particular container. I merely want to enter its filesystem so that I can poke around and have a look at how it's constructed.

This is the failing run:

```
$ docker run prismagraphql/prisma:1.21 --name blah
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: java.lang.RuntimeException: No valid Prisma config could be loaded.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
    at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:36)
    at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:14)
    at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:11)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:11)
    at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method for doing this is to create a new commit of the failing container and then invoke it with a new entrypoint.

#### Example

Get container ID

```
$ docker ps -a | grep prisma:1.21 | awk '{print $1}'
96b3a1ed8ae2
```

Create a new commit against this container ID

```
$ docker commit 29e98275723a tmpprisma
sha256:a83e0ee158d57f262230df752197a1f1e823660c42a9250e3c1ce803b41746c5
```

Enter the container's image with a new entrypoint

```
$ docker run -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash tmpprisma
bash-4.4#
```

Can now inspect the script that's used inside the container

```
bash-4.4# ls -l app/bin/prisma-local
-rwxr--r--    1 root     root         16474 Apr 30  2018 app/bin/prisma-local
bash-4.4#
```

#### References

- [Enter a stopped Docker container #27](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter/issues/27)